# Conditional formatting based on cell reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

How can I use conditional formatting to highlight a cell based on an entered cell reference?

For eg,

If I enter A1, cell A1 must be highlighted.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

`= SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(A1), COLUMN(A1)), "$", "")=$A$1`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I used `= ADDRESS(ROW(A1), COLUMN(A1), 4)` instead of the `SUBSTITUTE` function.